# HTML table with custom css design

Tags: html, css

*What is the proper way to create the table with HTML and CSS like in the image below?
I am struggling with this task for hours now...*
The problem is that I don't know how to organize row in the table to have layout like in the image below, all items should be in one row, but I have managed to have all in the separate row.

*HTML:*

```
<table class="testTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <strong>Order</strong>
          </th>
          <th>
            <strong>Operation</strong>
          </th>
          <th>
            <strong>Times</strong>
          </th>
          <th>
            <strong>Quantities</strong>
          </th>
          <th>
            <strong>Date</strong>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="bottom-border">Kamera</td>
          <td class="bottom-border" style="color: green;">
            <strong>PRODUCTION</strong>
          </td>
          <td class="bottom-border">7:85</td>
          <td class="bottom-border" style="color: green;">GOOD</td>
          <td class="bottom-border">26.06.2018.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kaciga</td>
          <td style="color: orange;">Undefined</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td style="color: orange;">SCRAP</td>
          <td>26.06.2018.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ventil</td>
          <td style="color: yellow;">Planned</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td style="color: yellow;">REWORK</td>
          <td>26.06.2018.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td style="color: red;">UnPlanned</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td style="color: red;">Destroyed</td>
          <td>26.06.2018.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

*CSS:*

```
.bottom-border { border-bottom: solid 1px black; }
.testTable{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        width:100%;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
.testTable tr{
        background: #f7f6f6;
    }
    /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
.testTable tr:hover {
          background-color: #6d7272;
}
```

*Thank you*

Comment: What have you already tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and maybe we can help from there.

Comment: Please share your code dude.

Comment: What have to you tried so far? Show some of your working. You're not going to get complete results asking questions like this on SO.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, I have a little problem with code formatting on the page. I have added the code example.

Comment: We found a solution, sorry once again about the discussion I have caused.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a slightly more constructive answer, for you to use as a starter for 10. You can utilise CSS3 `:nth` selectors.

For example:

**Selecting odd and even rows:**

```
tr:nth-child(even)
tr:nth-child(odd)
```

**Selecting the first two rows:**

```
tr:nth-child(-n+2)
```

Read more about [`nth-child()`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, "How do I create a table" though it does partially answer how to color rows but it's only one small part of the overall question which is thoroughly off topic, shouldn't be answered in the first place, and will soon be closed.

Comment: I'm not sure I said it was a complete answer, hence the reason saying **starter for 10**. I know how the site works @Rob. Not sure "thoroughly off topic" is strictly true, but thanks for you input.

Comment: Shouldn't answer these types of question anyway as they are off topic and attracts pretty rubbish answers like this that doesn't actually answer the OPs question - unless you are looking for a points grab?

Comment: If you ever read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer you would completely understand why you shouldn't be answering the question and why it's off topic.

Comment: Jeeeeze! Come on guys, lets not be so strict. Aside for reaching out via personal channels to @Originator. I thought I'd offer an olive branch, a little help, a starter for 10. It's not a complete answer, i wouldn't expect it to be marked as the right answer, nor am i trying to points grab, I was merely trying to help.

Comment: So, don't follow published SO policy and do what makes one feel good even though it breaks the said rules?

Comment: Don't complain to me, Alex. Complain to the SO mods. Let's see how far that gets you.

Comment: @Rob: "I no longer actively participate in Stack Overflow." Think you need to update your bio.

Comment: YOU are one of the reasons I posted that.

Comment: @Rob - People, there is no need to have bad karma. I admit this is my problem, the question was badly raised. I have added the code example, I have just hit the ask question by accident. Of course, I would set a code example. Thank you, Alex, for olive branch and Rob I will be very careful when asking the next question.

Comment: @Alex - People, there is no need to have bad karma. I admit this is my problem, the question was badly raised. I have added the code example, I have just hit the ask question by accident. Of course, I would set a code example. Thank you, Alex, for olive branch and Rob I will be very careful when asking the next question.